# Flexslider only Horizontal Slide not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

I [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048568/flexsider-do-not-slide-but-fade) already for the problem but i could now find exactly the error.. the ERROR appears only with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#banner-slider-text').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    direction: 'horizontal',
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Exactly only on "slide" with "horizontal" appears the problem that it dont slide ... when i look in the code view from chrome or firebug i see that the "activ" slide changed but not the visual. it dont slide anyways. SLide + Vertical work, Fade + Vertical work, Fade + Horizontal work, Slide + Horizontal NOT WORK.

```
Flexslider vers 2.*
JQuery ver 1.9 - 2.* testet 
Shopware vers 4.3.6
```

Slider is coded in smarty tpl with the Slider Options and loaded in the Home index tpl from the mainpage.

Comment: i cant post an image because reputation ... realy ? nice i cant show you the problem

Comment: the sympton only shows up in Shopware with smarty ... Hardcoded Flexslider in a static HTML works fine ....

Answer (score 0):

After alot of Debugging i found out that at code line 928 the style are set and here is the width with the slider.computedW variable is NaN ... thats the reason why with is dont Set ... and at code line 874 is the target for the transform translate3D NaN to ... i get no transform element for the animation

```
928
setTimeout(function(){
        slider.doMath();
        slider.newSlides.css({"width": slider.computedW, "float": "left", "display": "block"});
        // SMOOTH HEIGHT:
        if (slider.vars.smoothHeight) { methods.smoothHeight(); }
      }, (type === "init") ? 100 : 0);

874
if (slider.transitions) {
    target = (vertical) ? "translate3d(0," + target + ",0)" : "translate3d(" + target + ",0,0)";
    dur = (dur !== undefined) ? (dur/1000) + "s" : "0s";
    slider.container.css("-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur);
     slider.container.css("transition-duration", dur);
  }
```

maybe thats the reason why my slide Horizontal dont work .... but i am not sure